# Up-scaling an array in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library

I would like to make a PCD file with X, Y, Z, RGBA and Label fields. Now I have a XYZRGBA, PCD file. It includes 640*480 points. In the other hand I have another file which includes 320*256 numbers that represent labels in a segmented image. I want to up-scale the label array and add it to my current PCD file for making a new PCD files with corresponding x,y,z, rgba and label information.This PCD file will be related to a segmented image.
 Here is my attempt.
 Label is the name of file which contains label information, first I converted it to an OpenCV matrix and now I want to up-scale it to 640*480 and then add it to the current xyzrgba, pcd file. After Up-scaling again I converted the resulted OpenCV matrix to a normal matrix with name: "array" for adding to my current PCD data.

```
cv::Mat LabelsMat=cv::Mat(320,256, CV_32SC1, label); 
cv::Mat OriginalLabels=cv::Mat::zeros(320,256, CV_32SC1);
LabelsMat.copyTo(OriginalLabels);    
cv::Mat UpScaledLabels=cv::Mat::zeros(640, 480, CV_32FC1); 
cv::resize(OriginalLabels, UpScaledLabels, UpScaledLabels.size(), 0, 0,cv::INTER_NEAREST); 
std::vector<int> array;
array.assign((int*)UpScaledLabels.datastart, (int*)UpScaledLabels.dataend);
```

But there is some problem. When I make this new PCD file and want to see only one segment of the image, e.g. 4, a wrong shape is appeared to me which is very different with segment 4 according to my basic image. I am sure the problem is because of this part and above code. Does any one could help me in finding the problem please? I appreciate your valuable help.

Comment: `CV_32FC1` should be `CV_32SC1`, but that shouldn't be a problem, since OpenCV will reallocate the matrix itself. Can you add the declaration of variable `label`? Your resizing looks right to me... Can you please check whether `UpScaledLabels` is continuous after resizing?

Comment: are you sure that you use `array.assign` the right way? I guess it uses iterators instead of pointers... Please try to loop over the mat and push_back the entries instead, just for debugging...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My Label is the name of a ".dat" file and it's size is: 640*256, But because of being a space between every 2 numbers, the size of data is: 320*256. I read it with this instruction and put the data which are integer numbers and be used as the name of segments in a matrix named label=====> ifstream in("My_Labels.dat");

   for (i = 0; i < 320; i++) 
    for (j = 0;j< 256; j++) 
     {    
      in >> label[i][j];    
           }

  in.close();

Comment: And sorry what do yo mean by: "check whether UpScaledLabels is continuous after resizing"? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: so "label" is a int** ? openCV mat would need a int* as input when you create your LabelMat. try cv::Mat LabelsMat=cv::Mat(320,256, CV_32SC1, &label[0][0]);  please

Comment: I used your advise, but still that wrong shape is appeared to me as a specific segment...

Comment: can you upload a sample .dat file?

Comment: Dear Micka I do'nt know how can I upload my .dat file here, Could I send it to your email if possible?

Comment: best google "file hosting" and after upload post the link

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) here is the link of my ".dat" file: "http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/505603/00004_left-labels.dat"

Comment: And this is the image of my scene that I have its xyzrgba, pcd file and want to add labels to that. http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=33649394778655222452. The left yellow box is segment 4 but instead of seeing the box after separation of object 4. I only see a wrong shape as: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=34195946002936185160

Comment: thx alot, unfortunately I don't have more time today, but I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: and again this is my ".dat" file which includes labels: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=41653651941699680870

Comment: I appreciate the time that you devoted to me and my question. and any help from your side will be welcome. Thank you very much and best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally had the time...

It is always good to look at the Mat objects you produced, just use cv::imshow or cv::imwrite and scale the data accordingly.

Using this code (basically your own code with fixed array writing):

```
int label[320][256];

std::ifstream in("../inputData/UPSCALE_data.dat"); 
for (int i = 0; i < 320; i++) 
    for (int j = 0;j< 256; j++) 
    { 
        in >> label[i][j]; 
    } 
in.close();

// create Mat with label input:
cv::Mat LabelsMat=cv::Mat(320,256, CV_32SC1, label); 

cv::Mat OriginalLabels = LabelsMat.clone(); // you could instead work on the non-copied data, if you liked to...

// upscale:
cv::Mat UpScaledLabels; // no need to allocate memory here during testing
cv::resize(OriginalLabels, UpScaledLabels, cv::Size(640, 480), 0, 0,cv::INTER_NEAREST); 

std::vector<int> marray;
marray.reserve(UpScaledLabels.cols*UpScaledLabels.rows);
for(int j=0; j<UpScaledLabels.rows; ++j)
    for(int i=0; i<UpScaledLabels.cols; ++i)
    {
        marray.push_back(UpScaledLabels.at<int>(j,i));
    }

// now here marray has information about the upscaled image.


cv::Mat convertedCorrect;
UpScaledLabels.convertTo(convertedCorrect, CV_8UC1);

cv::imwrite("../outputData/UPSCALED_RESULT_ORIG.png", convertedCorrect*50);
```

I get this result:

[image]

That's because  `cv::Mat LabelsMat=cv::Mat(320,256, CV_32SC1, label);` produces an image with HEIGHT 320 and WIDTH 256 (I thought I already mentioned that in a comment but can't find it atm...)

So fixing that using this code:

```
int label[320][256];

std::ifstream in("../inputData/UPSCALE_data.dat"); 
for (int i = 0; i < 320; i++) 
    for (int j = 0;j< 256; j++) 
    { 
        in >> label[i][j]; 
    } 
in.close();

// create Mat with label input: HERE THE DIMENSIONS ARE SWAPPED
cv::Mat LabelsMat=cv::Mat(256,320, CV_32SC1, label); 

cv::Mat OriginalLabels = LabelsMat.clone(); // you could instead work on the non-copied data, if you liked to...

// upscale:
cv::Mat UpScaledLabels; // no need to allocate memory here during testing
cv::resize(OriginalLabels, UpScaledLabels, cv::Size(640, 480), 0, 0,cv::INTER_NEAREST); 

std::vector<int> marray;
marray.reserve(UpScaledLabels.cols*UpScaledLabels.rows);
for(int j=0; j<UpScaledLabels.rows; ++j)
    for(int i=0; i<UpScaledLabels.cols; ++i)
    {
        marray.push_back(UpScaledLabels.at<int>(j,i));
    }

// now here marray has information about the upscaled image.


cv::Mat convertedCorrect;
UpScaledLabels.convertTo(convertedCorrect, CV_8UC1);

cv::imwrite("../outputData/UPSCALED_RESULT_CORRECTED.png", convertedCorrect*50);
```

you get this Mat which looks much better:

[image]

But compared to your other image, that image is somehow rotated?!?

[image]

Comment: Oh, really thank you very muchhhhhhhhhhh. I will try it just now :)

Comment: The code works properly. Only in the second code section after swapping the dimensions it should be:  "cv::Mat LabelsMat=cv::Mat(256,320, CV_32SC1, label); " Now I have the segment 4 separately, as I wished in a right way: " http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=96806928338621923846  ", thanks a lot and God bless you :)

Comment: thank you! that was a copy/paste error on my side... so stupid :D edited that... hope you didn't waste too much time in finding that error in my answer -.-